# C# do many replacements at once in a String

Tags: c#, text

I have a dictionary of replacements

```cs
var substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "one", "two" },
    { "two", "three" },
};
```

I want to turn the string "one two three four" into "two three three four".

Running any kind of iterative replacement chain like

```cs
var phrase = "one two three four";
substitutions.Aggregate(phrase, (current, substitution) => current.Replace(substitution.Key, substitution.Value)));
```

or

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder(phrase);
foreach (var entry in substitutions)
{
    sb.Replace(entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
sb.ToString();
```

yields "three three three four" because the second replacement "two" → "three" is able to see the "one" → "two" output from the previous output.

How can I only replace "original" words?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the words will be separated by a white space? Could you turn the string `"one two three four"` into an `array [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ]` using [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: You can't run with iteration in one go. If you do so your output will be `three three three four`. `one` will be replace by `two` so you will have `two two three four` and then on the second loop it will replace everything again. You will need to split your string into word and find the correct replacement for each and replace once.

Comment: @NateW yes it's guaranteed one whitespace between words

Comment: I think you would need an intermediate structure with metadata that can track the changes and be used by subsequent steps to determine if a replacement should occur. Sounds like a lot of trouble, I'm really curious what the use case is for this.

Comment: How would you like to handle replacements that would be part of words? What if the input was `twentytwo` ? Would you want it to be `twentythree`, or left alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex as follows:

```
var substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "one", "two" },
    { "two", "three" },
};

var phrase = "one two three four";

var pattern = string.Join("|", substitutions.Keys.Select(Regex.Escape));

// Pattern is: one|two

var result = Regex.Replace(phrase, pattern, match => substitutions[match.Value]);
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m05f1D)

---

If the substitutions must only match complete words, you can update `pattern` to include word boundaries `\b`:

```
substitutions.Keys.Select(x => @$"\b{Regex.Escape(x)}\b")
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lPLbjP)

Comment: Perfect this is what I was looking for originally

Comment: Watch out for overflow exceptions. If you have too much replaces to do first of all this will be extremely slow and you might not be able to create the string object to that size

Answer (score 2):

Split the string into individual terms, now you can iterate just once and replace:

```
var phrase = "one two three four";
var terms = phrase.Split();

for(int i = 0; i < terms.Length; i++)
{
  if(substitutions.ContainsKey(terms[i]))
  {
    terms[i] = substitutions[terms[i]];
  }
}

phrase = string.Join(" ", terms);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's always single words split by space just split the string and loop through that collection to rebuild the new result

```
var substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "one", "two" },
    { "two", "three" },
};
var phrase = "one two three four";

// convert to list of words
var words = phrase.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

// keep the transformed result
var result = new StringBuilder();

// for each words
foreach (var word in words)
{
    // add a space before since we removed it.
    // will trim later on for the first useless space it creates
    result.Append(" ");

    // to get the dictionary value
    string substitutionWord;

    // if we found the dictionary key
    if (substitutions.TryGetValue(word, out substitutionWord))
    {
        // add substitution word instead
        result.Append(substitutionWord);
    }
    else // not found
    {
        // keep the original word
        result.Append(word);
    }
}

var finalResult = result.ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: This is going to add an extra space to the very beginning

Comment: @juharr no it's not there a trim

Comment: The problem is that if there were leading or trail spaces to begin with you've now removed them.